# Prune back history after completing activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have the following activity path:

```
Main -> A0 -> A1 -> A2 -> B
```

or

```
Main -> B
```

On `Main`, the user can select to either show something on `B`, or to create something new with the `A` series.
After completing the `A` series, it goes to `B`.

When the user gets to `B` via the `A` route, I want the back button to go to `Main`. But when the user is in the `A` series, I want the back button to go to the previous `A` (or `Main` from the first `A`).

I tried using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when I create the intents, but that just makes everything go back to `Main`.

Is there a way to mark the activities for removal once I hit a threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `BroadcastReceiver` in all activities you want to close (A0,  A1, A2):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private FinishReceiver finishReceiver;
    private static final String ACTION_FINISH = 
           "com.mypackage.MyActivity.ACTION_FINISH";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        finishReceiver= new FinishReceiver();
        registerReceiver(finishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unregisterReceiver(finishReceiver);
    }

    private final class FinishReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FINISH)) 
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

To close these activities trigger the following broadcast from Activity B.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_FINISH));
```

Here is the github example [project](https://github.com/ihrupin/samples/tree/master/android/Close_All_Activities_Prj) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Define the logic in this very way

In Series of Activity A define the logic in this very way

```
 public static Activity A=null;
  //in onCreate();

   A=this;

  //Same way in B
  public static Activity B=null;

  B=this
```

now wherever you want the back condition to be checked override the OnbackPressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
    {
    if(Activity_A.A!=null)
    {
    finish();
    return;
    }

    if(Activity_B.B!=null){
    //your condition
    finish();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a new intent for Main activity with SINGLE_TOP and CLEAR_TOP flags in onBackPressed of B. So no matter how you landed at B, pressing back takes you to Main with all history cleared. No need to mess with A series activities.